# Too many checks for empty params. How to optimize queries to ActiveRecord in Rails5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm doing checks for empty parameters before do the query.
There is only 1 check for *params[:car_model_id]*. I can imagine if I will add more checks for other params, then there will be a mess of if-else statements. It doesn't look nice and I think it can be optimized. But how? Here is the code of controller:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
def search
  if params[:car_model_id].empty?
    @cars = Car.where(
      used: ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(params[:used]), 
      year: params[:year_from]..params[:year_to], 
      price: params[:price_from]..params[:price_to], 
      condition: params[:condition]
      )
  else
    @cars = Car.where(
      used: ActiveRecord::Type::Boolean.new.cast(params[:used]), 
      car_model_id: params[:car_model_id], 
      year: params[:year_from]..params[:year_to], 
      price: params[:price_from]..params[:price_to], 
      condition: params[:condition]
      )
  end

  if @cars
    render json: @cars
  else
    render json: @cars.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick would be to remove the blank values, do a little bit of pre-processing (and possibly validation) of the data, and then pass the params to the `where` clause.

To help with the processing of the date ranges, you can create a method that checks both dates are provided and are converted to a range:

```
def convert_to_range(start_date, end_date)
  if start_date && end_date
    price_from = Date.parse(price_from)
    price_to = Date.parse(price_to)
    price_from..price_to
  end
rescue ArgumentError => e
  # If you're code reaches here then the user has invalid date and you       
  # need to work out how to handle this.
end
```

Then your controller action could look something like this:

```
# select only the params that are need
car_params = params.slice(:car_model_id, :used, :year_from, :year_to, :price_from, :price_to, :condition)

# do some processing of the data
year_from = car_params.delete(:year_from).presence
year_to = car_params.delete(:year_to).presence
car_params[:price] = convert_to_range(year_from, year_to)

price_from = car_params.delete(:price_from).presence
price_to = car_params.delete(:price_to).presence
car_params[:price] = convert_to_range(price_from, price_to)

# select only params that are present
car_params = car_params.select {|k, v| v.present? }

# search for the cars
@cars = Car.where(car_params)
```

Also, I'm pretty sure that the `used` value will automatically get cast to boolean for you when its provided to the `where`.

Also, `@cars` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which does not have an `errors` method. Perhaps you mean to give different results based on whether there are any cars returned?

E.g: `@cars.any?`  (or `@cars.load.any?` if you don't want to execute two queries to fetch the cars and check if cars exist)

**Edit:**

As mentioned by [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) you can also clean up your code by chaining `where` conditions and [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).  Scopes help to move functionality out of the controller and into the model which increases re-usability of functionality.

E.g.

```
class Car > ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :year_between, ->(from, to) { where(year: from..to) }
  scope :price_between, ->(from, to) { where(price: from..to) }

  scope :used, ->(value = true) { where(used: used) }

end
```

Then in your controller:

```
# initial condition is all cars
cars = Cars.all

# refine results with params provided by user
cars = cars.where(car_model_id: params[:car_model_id]) if params[:car_model_id].present?
cars = cars.year_between(params[:year_from], params[:year_to])
cars = cars.price_between(params[:price_from], params[:price_to])
cars = cars.used(params[:used])
cars = cars.where(condition: params[:condition]) if params[:condition].present?

@cars = cars
```

Comment: Might also be worth nothing that `M.where(a: 'b', c: 'd')` is the same as `M.where(a: 'b').where(c: 'd')` or even `ms = M.where(a: 'b'); ms = ms.where(c: 'd')` so you could factor out the common parts of the `if` and `else` branches easily enough. A little more flexible than manipulating a Hash as you can throw in scopes too.

Comment: I'm stuck at ```car_params.delete```

Debug from rails console:```
2.2.3 :035 > car_params[:year] = car_params.delete(:year_from)..car_params.delete(:year_to)
 => nil..nil 
2.2.3 :037 > Car.where(car_params)
  Car Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "cars".* FROM "cars" WHERE "cars"."car_model_id" = ? AND "cars"."used" = ? AND "cars"."condition" = ? AND ("cars"."year" BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND ("cars"."price" BETWEEN ? AND ?)  [["car_model_id", 1], ["used", true], ["condition", "perfect"], ["year", nil], ["year", nil], ["price", nil], ["price", nil]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> 
```

Comment: Request comes with empty parameters: ```"year_from"=>"", "year_to"=>"", "price_from"=>"", "price_to"=>""```
And .delete method converts it into ```..```

Comment: Ah yeah, you should probably also do a sanity check to make sure those params have actually been entered by the user.  I'll update the answer.

Comment: You'll probably also need to parse the string to an actual date... so I've update the answer with that too.  Just be careful with this as you may still get exceptions if the values in params for `year_from`, `year_to`, `price_from`, `price_to` are not valid dates

Comment: I've also extracted common functionality used to process the date ranges into a separate method.

Comment: Ended with checks like: 
`car_params[:year_from] = car_params[:year_from].presence ?car_params[:year_from].to_i : 1970` 
`car_params[:year_to] = car_params[:year_to].presence ? car_params[:year_to].to_i : Date.today.year` 
`car_params[:year] = car_params.delete(:year_from)..car_params.delete(:year_to) `